# running xcrysden in wayland

Tags: x11, wayland

I am trying to run xcrysden (http://www.xcrysden.org/Download.html, the semi-shared version) in fedora 36. First there were some dependencies with libTogl, which I have solved using https://forums.opensuse.org/showthread.php/553197-Can-t-run-xcrysden-crystallographic-software-Missing-library?p=3084804#post3084804
eg:

```
cd -
tar -zxvf ...
cd Togl2.0-8.4-Linux/lib
ln -s Togl2.0/libTogl2.0.so libTogl.so.2

edit the file .bashrc
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$HOME/Togl2.0-8.4-Linux/lib/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
```

Now the problem is, this is working on  x11, but in wayland, I am getting error:

```
Running on platform : unix
   Operating system : Linux
Package ImageMagick's convert: /usr/bin/convert
Package ImageMagick's import: /usr/bin/import
Executing: /tmp/xcrysden-1.6.2-bin-shared/bin/ftnunit
Error in startup script: 
Couldn't configure togl widget
    while executing
"togl .mesa  -width          400  -height         400  -ident          .mesa  -rgba           $toglOpt(rgba)           -redsize        $toglOpt(redsize..."
    (procedure "PlaceGlobWin" line 107)
    invoked from within
"PlaceGlobWin 0 [expr round(670 * $fac1)] [expr round(670 * $fac1)]"
    (procedure "ViewMol" line 25)
    invoked from within
"ViewMol ."
    invoked from within
"if { [llength $argv] > 2 } {
    parseComLinArg [lrange $argv 2 end]
} else {
    ViewMol .
}"
    (file "/tmp/xcrysden-1.6.2-bin-shared/Tcl/xcInit.tcl" line 633)
```

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu 22.04 i disabled the `Wayland = false` using following commands:

```
$ sudo vim /etc/gdm3/custom.conf
```

Un-commented there as

```
WaylandEnable=false
```

and finally

```
$ sudo systemctl restart gdm3
```

You can restart the system. After this the `apt install` of `xcrysden` worked for me.

Comment: Thank you sir. Seems a little bit like "Black Magic" but worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have met the issue of Xcrysden, which seems to work with X.org, not working Wayland, which is the default WM on fedora >31? or so. See these  issues on the xcrysden mailing list [here](http://www.democritos.it/pipermail/xcrysden/2021-June/002070.html) and [here](http://www.democritos.it/pipermail/xcrysden/2021-April/002056.html). There is solution which involved choosing "Gnome on Xorg" instead of Wayland, in the gear icon of the login page.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting same error for Xcrysden 1.6 on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. Compiling version [1.5.60](http://www.xcrysden.org/download/xcrysden-1.5.60-linux_x86_64-semishared.tar.gz) of Xcrysden worked for me with a small change in the script as mentioned below.

After extracting the tar file, edit the `xcrysden` file by going in the extracted directory and comment out the following line

```
unset MALLOC_CHECK_; # Lorenzo's suggestion !
```

which is present at the first few lines in the script.

Answer (score 0):

I am experiencing the same problem.

Did you manage to solve the issue?
If so, what is the working solution for you? Did you move back to Xorg or did you manage to compile a version (which number? shared/static?) of Xcrysden?

If I try to follow S. Kitt answer, I still get an error during compile.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/428220)